# How to use libphonenumber library in an ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, libphonenumber

I am facing with a problem on using libphonenumber library in ASP.NET. The following shows my usage of the library.

My `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    IsValidNumber("9629212444"); // Here I pass the value from textbox dynamically
}
```

My validation method:

```
bool IsValidNumber(string aNumber) {
    bool result = false;
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.Parse(aNumber,"IN");
    result = phoneNumberUtil.IsValidNumber(phoneNumber);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have to validate all International Telephone numbers(mobile and landline phone number with area code).

Comment: Are you uising this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/ ?

Comment: yes . i was downloaded from nuget.org

Comment: And what's the problem with it?

Comment: here i dont want pass default region code  phoneUtil.Parse(aNumber,"IN");

Comment: Do you want to get your default region code from your culture info or something?

Comment: yes .. i want to pass region code dynamically based on country

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on your question I suppose you are trying to achieve something like the following.

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
var regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.LCID);
string regionName = regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName; // regionName == IN
```

And also, if you want to use the current culture of your application you can use `CurrentCulture` property of the `CultureInfo`.

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: CultureInfo("hi-IN") we cant take dynamically ?

Comment: You can get the current culture of your application. I edited my answer.

Comment: No. My system CurrentCulture info is selected US but my current location is India so i want to pass (IN)

Comment: I do not think that would be a proper solution. You may be in U.S. but your phone number may belong to another country. Consider giving a chance to your users to select their country first. Then you can check the phone number with the exact code that I have provided.

Comment: You can use country codes with `RegionInfo` class. The name parameter in its constructor accepts country names and their two-letter region names such as _IN_ or _US_.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList runat="server"  ID="ddlCountry">
            <asp:ListItem Text="INDIA" Value="IND" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="US" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPhoneNo" OnTextChanged="txtPhoneNo_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
i have tried like that but am getting error var regionInfo = new RegionInfo(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
            regionName = regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName;

            IsValidNumber(txtPhoneNo.Text.Trim(), regionName);

Comment: error :The region name IND should not correspond to neutral culture; a specific culture name is required